# Slow Indefinite Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, timing, maple

This might have been asked before but I couldn't find the answer. I want to perform an indefinite integral. I tried it both on Mathematica and Maple and the commutation time is significantly different. It takes roughly 45 seconds on Mathematica while it's instantaneous with Maple. Could someone give an answer to why this is and how to speed up the computation on Mathematica? 
Here is the integral:

```
Integrate[-(1/((1/2 + x) (1.`15.048133091869577 - 0.7271265201866038` x - 
  0.14586605445765533` x^2 - 0.14353734279040942` x^3 - 
  0.34371764036609265` x^4 + 0.04221841339432375` x^5 - 
  6.584428946770302` x^6))), x] // Timing
```

Now I tried to speed it up by using Apart and Distribute like this

```
-(1/((1/2 + x) (1.`15.048133091869577 - 0.7271265201866038` x - 
 0.14586605445765533` x^2 - 0.14353734279040942` x^3 - 
 0.34371764036609265` x^4 + 0.04221841339432375` x^5 - 
 6.584428946770302` x^6)));
 Apart[%];
 Distribute[Integrate[%, x]] // Timing
```

But this I had to stop because it was giving me anything after several minutes. The workaround is to Distribute "integrate" and then replace it with Integrate.

```
-(1/((1/2 + x) (1.`15.048133091869577 - 0.7271265201866038` x - 
 0.14586605445765533` x^2 - 0.14353734279040942` x^3 - 
 0.34371764036609265` x^4 + 0.04221841339432375` x^5 - 
 6.584428946770302` x^6)));
 Apart[%];
 Distribute[integrate[%, x]];
 %/. integrate -> Integrate // Timing
```

And in this case, the computation only takes 0.04 seconds.

Note that all 3 approaches worked just fine on Maple and gave result as soon as I pressed enter.

Comment: I suspect the `Distribute[Integrate[...]]` is not doing what you intend. `Map` would get it done quickly. Try `e1=...; e2 = Apart[e1];Timing[Map[Integrate[#, x] &, e2]]`.

Comment: Thanks @DanielLichtblau ! Using Map is much faster. It's actually the fastest approach. I need to remember to use map more often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually better to use exact input for exact solvers:

```
N@Integrate[
   Rationalize[-(1/((1/2 + x) (1.`15.048133091869577 - 
           0.7271265201866038` x - 0.14586605445765533` x^2 - 
           0.14353734279040942` x^3 - 0.34371764036609265` x^4 + 
           0.04221841339432375` x^5 - 6.584428946770302` x^6))), 0], 
   x] // AbsoluteTiming

(*
{0.096958,
 -0.820105 Log[0.5 + x] + 
   0.0546737 (3.10295 Log[-0.627436 + x] + (1.4933 + 
        1.65819 I) Log[(-0.414587 - 0.597065 I) + x] + (1.4933 - 
        1.65819 I) Log[(-0.414587 + 0.597065 I) + x] + (1.37539 + 
        2.17793 I) Log[(0.338503 - 0.691313 I) + x] + (1.37539 - 
        2.17793 I) Log[(0.338503 + 0.691313 I) + x] + 
     6.15967 Log[0.773193 + x])}
*)
```

[`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) is a little faster than [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html):

```
N@Integrate[SetPrecision[
    -(1/((1/2 + x) (1.`15.048133091869577 - 0.7271265201866038` x - 
           0.14586605445765533` x^2 - 0.14353734279040942` x^3 - 
           0.34371764036609265` x^4 + 0.04221841339432375` x^5 - 
           6.584428946770302` x^6))),
    Infinity], x] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.059878, 
 1.80144*10^16 (4.5525*10^-17 (0.206864 Log[-1.25487 + 2 x] +
         (0.0995533 + 0.110546 I) Log[(-0.829175 - 1.19413 I) + 2 x] +
         (0.0995533 - 0.110546 I) Log[(-0.829175 + 1.19413 I) + 2 x] +
         (0.0916924 + 0.145195 I) Log[(0.677006 - 1.38263 I) + 2 x] +
         (0.0916924 - 0.145195 I) Log[(0.677006 + 1.38263 I) + 2 x] + 
         0.410645 Log[1.54639 + 2 x]) - 4.5525*10^-17 Log[1. + 2. x])}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That is precisely what I was looking for.